# SelectOutput malfunctioning

Tags: java, anylogic

Using a selectOutput I'm facing a problem (I think it's a malfunction). 
The condition is as follows:

```
main.controlLot[agent.orderID][workcenterID]==
  main.alreadyEntered[agent.orderID][workcenterID] || 
  agent.numberProductsInPallet ==
    ((int) selectFrom(routings)
      .where(routings.work_center.eq(Name))
      .where(routings.component_id.eq(agent.component))
      .firstResult(routings.palletization))
```

On enter I'm checking `self.condition(agent)` and when it is verified by the first segment of the condition `(main.controlLot[agent.orderID][workcenterID]==main.alreadyEntered[agent.orderID][workcenterID])` it does not go through the True port. However, self.condition(agent) returns True.

I placed the following code on exit (False) to confirm if the condition could change mid logic:

```
traceln(main.controlLot[agent.orderID][workcenterID] + " " + main.alreadyEntered[agent.orderID][workcenterID]);
traceln(agent.numberProductsInPallet);
traceln(self.condition(agent));
```

and the traceln(self.condition(agent) prints true. I don't understand why would it evaluate the condition as true but send the agent through the false port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might be related to the type of system you use. 
if you use the "pull" protocol (see: http://www.anylogic.com/blog?page=post&id=157) the agent will look ahead and evaluate the selectoutput, before it enters it. Since the time spent in the **selectoutput** object is 0, it has to do that.
if the condition changes *after* it has evaluated the **selectoutput** function, it will still choose the false path even though it's true.
to fix it, depending on your code, you could use a **queue** object. This will give the agent 1 additional timestep to relax the parameters and evaluate the condition correctly

Comment: That makes sense and I would say it is the correct answer to my problem. However, I have a *release* object prior to the *selectoutput* where the condition is already true. This would only be the correct answer if you tell me that the agent looks two objects ahead since the condition becomes true when it exits a *restricted area end* object and goes through a *release* object before entering the *selectoutput*.
Is this possible?

Thank you for the time spent answering this!

Comment: as far as I know, it does. it will look forward until it findes a queue or something where it is a allowed to spend a timestep, and a release object is one of those object that takes zero time and therefor it will proceed to look further ahead (see: http://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/_ELR/Release.html?resultof=%22%72%65%6c%65%61%73%65%22%20%22%72%65%6c%65%61%73%22%20).

Comment: the same goes for the restricted area end object (see http://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.xj.anylogic.help/html/_ELR/RestrictedAreaEnd.html)